# Azure Devops not building in Release configuration

Tags: c#, azure-devops

I'm using #if DEBUG, and when I use Azure Devops to build and deploy, it's still deploying in debug mode, and not release mode, even though it says the build configuration is release. What am I doing wrong? I'm not as experienced in this realm, so I will happily edit/update this question to be more clear, since I'm pretty sure I need to add more detail, but not sure what I would need to add.

ETA: task variables per request

[image: Task Variables]
[image: Here's my variables]
[image: Set at release variable]

Comment: Just because you have a variable set doesn't mean whatever step is compiling your code is going to use it. Are you using the `$(BuildConfiguration)` variable in that step?

Comment: Can you show the task that is actually building the code?

Comment: @gunr2171 I think this is the answer. I added "release" to the Configuration and it seems to work, and ignore my #if DEBUG code. If you post your response here as the answer I'll mark it correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting build-time variables *alone* is not enough to get a pipeline task to perform as you want. Unless the task has some hidden functionality (which usually they don't), you need to explicitly *use* the variable in your task.

Variables, like your `BuildConfiguration` variable, are arbitrarily named. That means you need to be explicit in your use of the variable.

In the circled region here:

[image]

Either hard-code the configuration you want to use (`Release` or `Debug`), or use the variable syntax to use the variable value.

```
$(BuildConfiguration)
```

---

Note: you're going to want to make sure you use "Release" or "Debug", WITH the capital starting letter. If you ever make the move to Linux, compiling with "release" rather than "Release" will cause you to have different folder names than you expect, and because Linux's file system is case sensitive, it might introduce bugs in your pipeline.